# Why does Magento create batch_xx.tmp file in var/tmp folder

Tags: magento

Why does Magento create batch_xx.tmp file in var/tmp folder. This file actually contains list of customers with full email address. To comply with certain regularity issues, we can not store customer information in plain file but, this is creating problem

Answer (score 0):

That is a temporary file created by the dataflow export process. Specifically in app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Batch/Io.php.